# SQL Server Return top X rows with table join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've simplified the problem as much as possible.

I'm adding rows from an invoice table into a temp table. Each ID in the temp table is unique:

```
SELECT i.InvoiceID
INTO #Invoice
FROM [dbo].[Invoice] 
WHERE invoiceID IN ('4edf2fa1-2ac7-4e0c-bf38-9675831079bc',
                    'c262026b-8643-4654-943c-db24f3d9f534',
                    '6a6530eb-4c15-4bdf-9ea8-9cc42e0a2636')
```

Next I want to join that temp table to another another table called Items that has a foreign key for `InvoiceID`. The following query returns all items associated with each invoice:

```
SELECT i.invoiceid, itm.ItemID 
FROM #Invoice i
INNER JOIN [dbo].Item itm ON itm.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
```

However, I only want to return max the top 10 Items for each Invoices. Obviously if I add top 10 it will only return 10 rows, rather than 10 per invoice.

My motivation for this is that the SQL script is timing out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are the number of InvoiceIds is fixed to 3 or it can have more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with ties

```
SELECT TOP 10 WITH TIES 
   i.invoiceid, 
   itm.ItemID 
FROM 
    #Invoice i
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].Item itm
    ON itm.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
ORDER BY 
    row_number() over (partition by i.invoiceid order by i.invoiceid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just updated the question mentioning that my motivation is that my existing SQL script is timing out.

Comment: The timing out could be a bad query plan. Can you use Brent Ozar past the plan and include your execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way uses `cross apply`:

```
SELECT i.invoiceid, itm.ItemID
FROM #Invoice i CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (10) itm.*
      FROM [dbo].Item itm
      WHERE itm.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
      ORDER BY ???  -- however you define the top items
     ) itm;
```

For performance, you want an index on `Item(InvoiceId, ???)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just updated the question mentioning that my motivation is that my existing SQL script is timing out.